# gcc linking object file and library - what is the difference?

Tags: linux, gcc

Let's say that there is this command:

```
g++ main.o somefile.o -lc -o main
```

What is the difference between linking object file somefile.o and linking library libc.a?

Comment: By default, it is the shared object library `libc6.so` which is linked thru `-lc` and it is also linked at runtime, entirely. See also http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files ending in ".a" are archive files. They essentially contain a set of ".o"s. Therefore, assuming "libc.a" contains "c1.o", "c2.o" and "c3.o", your command is essentially equivalent to unarchiving "libc.a", then invoking:

```
g++ main.o somefile.o c1.o c2.o c3.o -o main
```

Note that, the objects contained in the ".a" are only included if required, i.e., if at least one of their symbols is referenced by another ".o".

Comment: But with a subtle difference, if there is no symbols needed from c?.o, then that object is not included in the linking, IIRC.

Comment: Also, `.a` is not a compressed format. Its constituents are simply "unarchived".

Comment: @larsmans: I reworded my answer so as not to suggest compression. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: +1 if you add @rodrigo's comment into the answer. That's pretty crucial; some people build `.a` files full of optional modules to let the linker find out which ones are actually needed and simplify build scripts (at the expense of speed, obviously).

Comment: @larsmans Could you please provide a reference for that. I remember hearing about it too, but can't find where it is documented.

Comment: @user1202136: it's easy to test. Compile a function that prints `Hello` and one that prints `world`, put them in `libhw.a`, then link two different programs with that, one that calls the first function and one that prints the second. Run `strings` on the programs and you'll see only one of the strings winds up in either program.